# Why does Dismax's bq (Boost Query) parameter filter results instead of just boosting them?

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 8.11.2. In order to boost documents with certain field values, I'm using Dismax's bq (Boost Query) parameter.

From what I've read, this should only influence the score of the search results returned by the rest of the query. What I see happening is that it filters all search results that don't have the field I'm boosting.

I'm using the following query, which returns all documents containing both words **procedure** and **maintenance**:

q=((+procedure+maintenance))&rows=10&start=0&wt=xml&q.op=AND&fl=id,score,alias,author,hash,collection,label,url,lastModified,path,extension,objectId,objectDtType,title,DocumentPK_s,Taal_s,Site_s,SharePointId_s&hl=true&hl.qt=highlightRH&hl.fl=content,description,label&hl.snippets=5&defType=dismax&bf=recip(max(0,ms(NOW-3MONTH,creationDate)),3.16e-11,1,1)&pf=content&sort=score DESC

But as soon as I append **&bq=language:english^10000**, which is supposed to boost documents where the field **language** is set to **english**, all documents where the field **language** doesn't exist are no longer part of the results.

Am I misunderstanding how this parameter is supposed to work? Is it a side effect?

Comment: Could you please share more information about the query?

Comment: I've added the query I'm using to test, along with some detail.